10 questions migrated from Gamification
Just a FYI: Gamification was closed in private beta. As there was some overlap in scope with this site, some of the questions posted there were migrated here after it was closed. These may need some work to make them suitable for this site:

Has there been any research done that contrasts point-based and achievement-based gamification methods?
Can rewards incentivise shortcuts to be taken which wouldn't be done otherwise?
How can I incentivize users to perform creative tasks?
How can employee anxiety over poor evaluation be avoided by management?
Which human instincts do gamification systems appeal to?
Are points still a relevant mechanic?
Are there specific game mechanics that correlate with addictions?
How can we determine an appropriate rate of decay for our scoring algorithms?
What is the difference between (and importance of) extrinsic vs. intrinsic rewards in gamification?
How can you gamify the recruitment of new employees?


I have tagged them, but please feel free to make additional edits and/or add other appropriate tags as needed!

Thanks for migrating them! They seem like a great addition to CogSci!
